# static class to Dictionary<string, string> in c#

Tags: c#, static, static-classes

I have a static class which only contains string properties. I want to convert that class into a name-value pair dictionary with `key=PropName`, `value=PropValue`.

Below is the code I have written:

```
void Main()
{
            Dictionary<string, string> items = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                var type = typeof(Colors);
                var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static);

                /*Log  properties found*/
                            /*Iam getting zero*/
                Console.WriteLine("properties found: " +properties.Count());

                foreach (var item in properties)
                {
                    string name = item.Name;
                    string colorCode = item.GetValue(null, null).ToString();
                    items.Add(name, colorCode);
                }

                /*Log  items created*/
                Console.WriteLine("Items  in dictionary: "+items.Count());
}

    public static class Colors
    {
        public static  string Gray1 = "#eeeeee";
        public static string Blue = "#0000ff";
    }
```

### Output

```
properties found: 0
Items  in dictionary: 0
```

It's not reading any properties - can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You should make your fields `readonly`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The members in your `Colors` class are no [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) but [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx).

Use [`GetFields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getfields.aspx) in the place of the GetProperties method.

You might end up with something like (also not the change in the call to `GetValue`):

```
                var properties = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static);

                /*Log  properties found*/
                            /*Iam getting zero*/
                Console.WriteLine("properties found: " +properties.Count());

                foreach (var item in properties)
                {
                    string name = item.Name;
                    string colorCode = item.GetValue(null).ToString();
                    items.Add(name, colorCode);
                }
```

Comment: so is there a way to make a dictionary!!

Comment: Replace the call to `GetProperties` with `GetFields` and the call to `GetValue` should have only one argument (null, because they are static fields).

Answer (score 4):

You can use linq to condense the conversion to a couple of lines:

```
var type = typeof(Colors);
var fields = type.GetFields().ToDictionary(f => f.Name, f => f.GetValue(f).ToString());
```

Comment: thanx for help. Upvoted ur answer, cant accept  as GvS answered it much before u and i can accept only one answer.

Comment: @Rusi - GvS actually answered the question so fully deserves to have the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var properties = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public);
```

Comment: Did you also use `BindingFlags.Public` ?